# Simple composite control - postback not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I am trying to make a simple composite control - just a label and textbox - but the postback isn't being picked up by the control.

I haven't implemented IPostBackDataHandler as according to [this its not necessary - the TextBox control should tie in automagically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479016.aspx).

> A composite control that includes a
>   TextBox need not worry about
>   postbacks, as the embedded control
>   will work it out with ASP.NET
>   automatically.

```
class TestControl : WebControl
{
    Label _label;
    TextBox _textbox;       

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        _label = new Label();
        _label.Text = "Some Label ";
        Controls.Add(_label);

        _textbox = new TextBox();
        Controls.Add(_textbox);

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
```

EDIT - I've inspected Context.Request.Form.Items and verified that the form data is getting back OK. I've also put a basic TextBox on the page directly and that works fine.

Comment: Shouldn't you derive your control from WebControl?

Comment: where do you "pick up" the postback event? that's not part of the code you posted. what is listening for that event?

Comment: Try inheriting from compositecontrol instead, this is a base class specifically for this scenario...

Comment: @WebControl - had tried both Control and WebControl - bad edit, fixing now.

Comment: @Artemiy - shouldn't have to as the TextBox control does that according to MSDN link referenced

Comment: @Brian - just tried CompositeControl, no luck.

Comment: @Brian - you were right, : CompositeControl - I had borked something else when I tested it the first time. Put in as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inheriting from compositecontrol instead, this is a base class specifically for this scenario..  Thanks.